# Loopback filter using related model field

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

Imagine we have two tables, `session` and `movie` in postgresql. The table `session` has a foreignkey to `movie`. How can i define a relation in `movie` so that i can ask for movies with filters on `session`. This table, for example, has a column `created` and i want to ask for results that has sessions after today with a custom method in Movies.js.

Comment: What you're referring to is a join... and LoopBack doesn't natively support joins in CRUD methods. You can write the query yourself using the datasource and then expose the data over a remote method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what i'm going to do!

Answer (score -1):

The table session has a foreignkey to movie, then you can define relations on both models(use a custom foreign key if necessary). Then, you can simply query data through the relation you have already defined. just use `find`, `include`, `scope` and `where` to get the data you want. If you can paste your json files for both models, it will be easy to figure it out.